# does this series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \ln(1 + \sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\ln(1 +  \sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$

The only thing I've figured out is:

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }  \ln(1 +  \sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}) =  \ln(1 +  \sin1) +  \ln(1 +  \sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) + \dots +  \ln(1 +  \sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})+ \dotsm$

And we can write the sum of logarithms as:

$\ln((1+ \sin 1)(1 +  \sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})...(1 +  \sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}) ...$

What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a direct comparison you may use

- $(\star)$: $\ln(1+x) \geq \frac{x}{1+x}$ for $x> 0$ which is easy to show using $\log(1+x) = \int_0^{x}\frac{dt}{1+t}$.
- $(\star\star)$: $\sin x \geq \frac{2}{\pi x}$ for $x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ (concavity of $\sin x$ on the given interval)

\begin{eqnarray} \sum _{n=1}^{N } \ln(1 + \sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})
& \stackrel{(\star)}{\geq} & \sum _{n=1}^{N } \frac{\sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{1 + \sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\\
& \geq & \frac 12\sum _{n=1}^{N } \sin\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \\
& \stackrel{(\star\star)}{\geq} & \frac 1\pi\sum _{n=1}^{N } \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\\
& \stackrel{N\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} & +\infty
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 3):

Note that\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)\right)}{\frac1{\sqrt n}}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log\left(1+\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)\right)-\log1}{\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)}\times\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)}{\frac1{\sqrt n}}\\&=1\times1\\&=1.\end{align}Since the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt n}$ diverges…

Comment: Could you explain a little? You're trying to estimate this sequence from the bottom?

Comment: I am applying the comparaison test. To be more precise, I compared your series with the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt n}$, which diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Composing Taylor series, start with the usual
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^5\right)$$
Make $x=\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$ to get
$$\sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=\frac{1}{n^{\frac 12}}-\frac{1}{6n^{\frac 32}}+\cdots $$
Now, the usual

$$\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ and use $x=\frac{1}{n^{\frac 12}}-\frac{1}{6n^{\frac 32}}$ to get
$$\log \left(1+\sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{n^{\frac 12}}-\frac 1 {2n}+\frac{1}{6n^{\frac 32}}+\cdots$$